# php user registered data related

Tags: php, mysql

Suppose the user had been registered in 2014(count any month and date).

Now the current year is 2017(count current date and time). My question is how can create a select option list with all years from beginning to now like

`2014.
2015.
2016.
2017.`

also there will be a another select Which will show the month list for the selected year.

Note: If the registered month is May 2014 then on the month select it will start from May.

Hope I explained well.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: How far have you come already?

Comment: Sorry. It's getting confusing for me. I am in 0.